# Can I get an exit code from running regedit /s?

Tags: vbscript, exit-code, regedit

I have a script that changes a registry value, before doing that, it makes a backup of the registry key using `regedit /e` to create a .reg file.

If the script is run a second time and the .reg backup file exists, I am asking the user if they want to add their backup back into the registry.

Because I don't want to confuse users who will have no real idea of whats happening with extra prompts they might not understand, I am using the following code to do this with out asking the user if they want to import:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run"regedit /s "  & """" & BackupFile & """" , 0, True
```

Is there a way to get a exit code from the `regedit` command for success or failure of `regedit` importing the backup .reg file?

Answer (score 6):

`regedit` doesn't return a status code. Use `reg.exe` with the `import` subcommand instead:

```
rc = objShell.Run("reg import """ & BackupFile & """" , 0, True)

If rc = 0 Then
  WScript.Echo "Import successful."
Else
  WScript.Echo "Import failed. (" & rc & ")"
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 Return = objShell.Run("regedit /s "  & """" & BackupFile & """" , 0, True)
```

`Return` contains the returned value.

Comment: Duh. I'm not thinking straight, of course. Can't believe I forgot that.

Comment: It always seems to work, i tried changing the permissions on the registry key but it still worked. do you know anyway to force this to fail so i can test failures?

Comment: that doesn't seem to be working. I always get an return code of 0 even when it doesn't work.

Comment: The code is good, the problem is with regedit.exe itself, see answer by @AnsgarWiechers