# Import registry from files

Tags: c++, registry

I have two problems with importing the registry from a file.

I import my registry files with regedit.exe:

```
string file = "regedit.exe /s D://ImageArchiveHour-1207150440.reg";
const char* ctv = file.c_str(); 

bool result = system(ctv);
```

In my example, the registry file is successfully imported, but the result is false. How can I get results of importing?

The other problem is, if my registry file path contain `SPACE`, import will fail.

For example:

```
string file = "regedit.exe /s D://New Folder//ImageArchiveHour-1207150440.reg";
const char* ctv = file.c_str(); 

system(ctv);
```

As you can see there is space in New Folder.

How should I fix this? Or is there any other way to do that?

Comment: `regedit` will not return exit code, so, `system` will return 0, that means, that all is ok. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18296926/vbscript-can-i-get-an-exit-code-from-running-regedit-s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0` is the result of importing. [system](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/277bwbdz.aspx) returns `-1` on error, but see the link for the possible return values. If all is okay, it will return the exit code of the `regedit` operation, 0 = [ERROR_SUCCESS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

> If command is NULL and the command interpreter is found, returns a nonzero value. If the command interpreter is not found, returns 0 and sets errno to ENOENT. If command is not NULL, system returns the value that is returned by the command interpreter. It returns the value 0 only if the command interpreter returns the value 0. A return value of – 1 indicates an error, and errno is set to one of the following values:...

The operation fails with a space because of the way [command line parameters are parsed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17w5ykft.aspx). You need to enclose your path in quotes (see [MSDN C++ Character Literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6aw8xdf2.aspx)).

So your

`string file = "regedit.exe /s D://ImageArchiveHour-1207150440.reg";`

would be

`string file = "regedit.exe /s \"D://ImageArchiveHour-1207150440.reg\"";`

Comment: Thank you so much for really fast reply and ofcurse solution for my problem, Path problem fixed

Answer (score 0):

I see you have got the answer, but I want to tell that if there is a space in the path of some file you should use quotes; so I would write the string as: 
`string file = "regedit.exe /s \"D://New Folder//ImageArchiveHour-1207150440.reg\""`